# Making Sync calls using promises Angular JS factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to make sync calls using a factory pattern.

```
$scope.doLogin = function (username, password, rememberme) {
        appKeyService.makeCall().then(function (data) {
//            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            debugAlert("login controller app key service"+data);
            var appkeyvalue = data.d.appkey;
            sessionConfigurationService.setBasicToken(appkeyvalue);

            loginService.makeCall(username, password, rememberme).then(function (accessTokenData) {
                if (accessTokenData.access_token !== "")
                {
                    sessionConfigurationService.setAccessTokenData(accessTokenData.access_token);
                    userPreferencesService.makeCall().then(function (userPreferencesData) {
                        if (userPreferencesData.d.userId !== "")
                        { 
                            sessionConfigurationService.setUserPreferences(userPreferencesData.d);
//                            $window.location.href = '/base.html';
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

My appKeyService factory is

```
app.factory('appKeyService', function ($q, authenticatedServiceFactory, configurationService) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var service = {};

    service.makeCall = function () {
        debugAlert("appKeyService async method request start");
         authenticatedServiceFactory.makeCall("GET", configurationService.getAppKeyURL(), "", "").then(function (data) {
            debugAlert("appKeyService async method response")
            deffered.resolve(data);
        });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
    return service;
});
```

My authenticated service factory is

```
app.factory('authenticatedServiceFactory', function ($http, $q, sessionConfigurationService) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var service = {};
    service.makeCall = function (methodType, URL, data, authType) {

        var headerValue = "";
        if (authType === "Basic") {
            headerValue = sessionConfigurationService.getBasicToken();
        } else if (authType === "Bearer") {
            headerValue = sessionConfigurationService.getBearerToken();
        }

        var config = {headers: {
                'Authorization': headerValue,
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            async: false
        };
        if (methodType === "GET") {
            $http.get(URL, data, config)
                    .then(function (getData) {
                        debugAlert("GET method response" + JSON.stringify(getData));
                        deffered.resolve(getData.data);
                    }, function (error) {
                        debugAlert("GET method response error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        deffered.reject(error);
                    });
        }
        else if (methodType === "POST") {
            $http.post(URL, data, config)
                    .then(function (putData) {
                        debugAlert("POST method response" + JSON.stringify(putData));
                        deffered.resolve(putData.data);
                    }, function (error) {
                        debugAlert("POST method response error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        deffered.reject(error);
                    });
        }
        else if (methodType === "DELETE") {
            $http.delete(URL, data, config)
                    .then(function (deleteData) {
                        debugAlert("DELETE method response" + JSON.stringify(deleteData));
                        deffered.resolve(deleteData.data);
                    }, function (error) {
                        debugAlert("DELETE method response error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        deffered.reject(error);
                    });
        }
        else if (methodType === "PUT") {
            $http.put(URL, config)
                    .then(function (putData) {
                        debugAlert("PUT method response" + JSON.stringify(putData));
                        deffered.resolve(putData.data);
                    }, function (error) {
                        debugAlert("PUT method response error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        deffered.reject(error);
                    });
        }
        return deffered.promise;
    };
    return service;
});
```

But I don't see the service calls are made in sync. So the "then" part in the controller is not executing **after** we receive the response. Its executing one after the other. How can I make that happen.

Comment: For the beginning, you should put var deffered = $q.defer(); in the service.makeCall functions

Comment: Promises don't make your code synchronous. They just help (a lot) with writing asynchronous code.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! You should not need a single `$q.defer();` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

@Frane Poljak

Thank you for your comment. I just brought

```
var deffered = $q.defer();
```

inside the makeCall method and its working as I wanted now. Thank you!

```
app.factory('appKeyService', function ($q, authenticatedServiceFactory, configurationService) {
    var service = {};

    service.makeCall = function () {
    var deffered = $q.defer();

        debugAlert("appKeyService async method request start");
         authenticatedServiceFactory.makeCall("GET", configurationService.getAppKeyURL(), "", "").then(function (data) {
            debugAlert("appKeyService async method response")
            deffered.resolve(data);
        });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
    return service;
});
```